# update numericInput based on the value selected from a dataset in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I need to return the age0 value from a dataset, if the user selected a patient. The numericInput field may allow override of the dataset values.

The code below was supposed to return a prediction based on the values selected, but it's not filling the age0 field when i select a patient.

Can you please help me fix this?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "patient", label = "Select a patient:",
              choices = c("new patient", unique(data_clean$ind)),
              selected = "new patient"),
  numericInput("K0", "K0:", value=0),
  numericInput("AL0", "AL0:", value=0),
  numericInput("CF", "CF:", value=0),
  numericInput("LT", "LT:", value=0),
  numericInput("age0", "Initial age:", value=0),

  numericInput("age1", "Final age:", value=0),
  
  
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "result")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  m1 <- lmer(CA1 ~ K0 + AL0 + CF + LT + age1 + age0 + (1|ind), data = data_clean, REML=FALSE)


  selected_age0 <- reactive({
    if (input$patient == "new patient") {
      0
    } else {
      data_clean[data_clean$ind == input$patient, "age0"]
    }
  })

  
  observe({
    updateNumericInput(session, "age0", value = selected_age0())
  })  

  prediction <- reactive({
    
    patient <- input$patient
    K0 <- input$K0
    AL0 <- input$AL0
    CF <- input$CF
    LT <- input$LT
    age0 <- log10(input$age0/365)
    age1 <- log10(input$age1/365)
    
    newdata <- data.frame(ind = patient, K0 = K0, AL0 = AL0, CF = CF, LT = LT, age0 = age0, age1 = age1)
    
    result1 <- predictInterval(merMod = m1, newdata = newdata,
                                 level = 0.90, n.sims = 1000,
                                 stat = "median", type="linear.prediction",
                                 include.resid.var = TRUE, seed=123)
    
    result1$fit
  })
  
  output$result <- renderPrint({ 
    
    paste0("Prediction: ", prediction())
    
  })
```

| ind | age0 | K0 | AL0 | CF | LT | age1 | CA1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1BD | -0.049 | 47.06 | 19.84 | 3.57 | 3.52 | 0.528 | 4.07 |
| 1BE | -0.019 | 46.06 | 19.92 | 3.77 | 3.45 | 0.528 | 3.68 |
| 2BD | -0.082 | 45.56 | 21.65 | 3.96 | 3.22 | 0.163 | 4.74 |
| 2BE | -0.082 | 44.87 | 21.47 | 3.93 | 3.22 | 0.163 | 4.71 |

Comment: Please post some sample data from `data_clean` in your question, if you want someone to help you.

Comment: As @YBS says, we need to see some data to make your example reproducible.  Absent that, my first guess would be that you need `observeEvent(selected_age0(), {updateNumericInput...`.  But without test data we are just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you subset `data_clean`:

You should use

`data_clean[data_clean$ind == input$patient, ][["age0"]]`

instead of

`data_clean[data_clean$ind == input$patient, "age0"]`

The former returns a vector, the later a `data.frame`.

And please try to make your examples more minimal, most of the code wasn't needed to reproduce the issue:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

set.seed(123)
data_clean <- tibble(ind = paste0(sample(0:9, 160, replace = TRUE),
                                  sample(LETTERS, 160, replace = TRUE),
                                  sample(LETTERS, 160, replace = TRUE)),
                     age0 = runif(160),
                     K0 = runif(160),
                     AL0 = runif(160),
                     CF = runif(160),
                     LT = runif(160),
                     age1 = runif(160),
                     CA1 = runif(160)
)


shinyApp(ui =  fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "patient", label = "Select a patient:",
              choices = c("new patient", unique(data_clean$ind)),
              selected = "new patient"),
  numericInput("K0", "K0:", value=0),
  numericInput("AL0", "AL0:", value=0),
  numericInput("CF", "CF:", value=0),
  numericInput("LT", "LT:", value=0),
  numericInput("age0", "Initial age:", value=0),
  
  numericInput("age1", "Final age:", value=0),
  
  
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "result")
  
), server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  selected_age0 <- reactive({
    if (input$patient == "new patient") {
      0
    } else {
      data_clean[data_clean$ind == input$patient, ][["age0"]]
    }
  })
  
  
  observe({
    updateNumericInput(session, "age0", value = selected_age0())
  })  
  
})
```